# How to Programmatically Populate Duplicate Detail Key Fields in Delphi FireDac

Tags: database, postgresql, delphi, firemonkey, master-detail

I am trying to set up a relational database in Delphi FireDac. I need the detail key field to match the master key. This will require duplicate data in the detail key field.

I attempted to populate the field in the `AfterInsert` event of the `TFDTable`, but got the error

> "field 'id' cannot be modified"

I also tried setting the `AutoGenerateValue` of the `TFDTable` to `arDefault`, but have not been able to update the record. I get the error

> null value in column "id" of relation "line" violates not-null constraint

The field is defined as `not null` but not `unique` or `primary key`.

How can I generate the same value in multiple detail key fields as the master primary key?

Comment: You specify the detail key field value in the insert statement. Or did I miss something here?

Comment: @Freddie Bell I edited the post. As the data is in a TDBGrid, I have no insert statement. Or do I need to have one?

Comment: Use the onnewrecord event  of the detail table to set the value

Comment: @SergeGirard, thank you much for your comment. I tried that too but got the 'field cannot be modified' error.

Comment: Well, if so, I need some more information on your detail table structure, or at least ask you if you declared fields. If you declare fields, check that the id_master field is not read only.

Comment: @SergeGirard, I had the detail key field set to read only. I changed that and it works. Not sure why I didn't think of that before, sure would have saved some headache. If you post it as an answer I will accept. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you post it as an answer I will accept

Use the OnNewRecordEvent of the Detail table.
Ensure detail key field is not read-only, especially if you declared fields via EDI contextual menu.

Let us say you have a "master" table Artists

```
CREATE TABLE artists (
ArtistId INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                        NOT NULL,
Name     NVARCHAR (120));
```

And detail table Albums

```
CREATE TABLE albums (
AlbumId  INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                        NOT NULL,
Title    NVARCHAR (160) NOT NULL,
ArtistId INTEGER        NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (
    ArtistId
)
REFERENCES artists (ArtistId) ON DELETE NO ACTION
                              ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

then ArtistId have to be read/write